# Arduino ESP8266 not sending POST request to Lumen PHP API

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I've created an API route with Lumen and have tested it with a POST request in Postman - all working fine.

However, when trying to send a POST request from ESP8266 with AT commands, I'm not having much success. The ESP8266 has an arduino serial converter. I get a 400 'bad request' error. The commands I have been using are below - are there any headers I'm missing? Or am I doing something else wrong? I have included the error response too.

I'm pretty new to this - any help is appreciated!
Cheers

**AT Commands:**

```
POST /v0.1/log HTTP/1.1
Host: XX.XX.X.XXX
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 37
Connection: Close
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"Value1":22,"Value2":45,"Value3":98}
```

**Error Response**

[image: Error Response]

Comment: Have you tried any JSON and Http libraries instead of AT commands.

Comment: That HTTP request should only be 179 bytes not 207 bytes. Is it really the same request that you have actually sent?

Comment: Is the endpoint `xx.xx.xx.xx/v0.1/log` correct on your server as per your http request `POST /v0.1/log HTTP/1.1`?

Comment: @SandunIsuruNiraj Thanks for the suggestion, I'll have a look into those.

Comment: @gre_gor Sorry, yes the error response was just an example. The commands being sent are correct with what I've been using.

Comment: @hcheung Yes that's the right endpoint - I've even tried free online HTTP request catchers, and I get the same error :(

Thanks for all the responses!